# Can I define a XAML element in the ViewModel and use it directly in the View using C++/WinRT and WinUI 3?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, winui-3, c++-winrt

Many questions have been asked about using a XAML element from the View in the ViewModel. But what about defining a XAML element in the ViewModel and using that in the XAML markup of the View? So that the ViewModel knows about the element from the get-go(and *owns* the element).

I was trying to do this thinking it would be more MVVM-compliant--the ViewModel doesn't have to know about the entire View in order to use this component. But I recognize it's still not really in the spirit of MVVM to define a XAML element in the ViewModel. But at this point, I just want to know if this technique is possible.

I know I can define a *property* in the ViewModel, and then bind that to a *property* of a XAML element defined in the View. E.g. defining a string in the ViewModel and binding that to the Text property of a TextBlock XAML element. But is it possible to simply define the XAML element itself in the ViewModel and use that in the XAML markup of the View?

Example code. I'm using C++/WinRT with WinUI 3:

**MainWindowViewModel.idl**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    runtimeclass FooViewModel
    {
        MainWindowViewModel();
        Int32 IntProperty; // I can bind this to a XAML element's property
        Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame Frame; // Can I use this in the View?
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.idl** (View)

```
import "ViewModel/MainWindowViewModel.idl";
namespace MyApp
{
    runtimeclass MainWindow : Micorosoft.UI.Xaml.Window
    {
        MainWindow();
        MainWindowViewModel MainWindowViewModel{ get; };
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml** (View's XAML)

```
<Window
    x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    //...
    >

    <StackPanel>
        // I can bind to a property of MainWindowViewModel as such:
        <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="{x:Bind MainWindowViewModel.IntProperty}" />

        // Is there a way to use the Frame defined in MainWindowViewModel here, or can you only create a new Frame instance?
        <Frame/>
    </StackPanel
</Window>
```

Comment: I would argue that your ViewModel does more than a ViewModel should do if it is creating a view component.

Comment: Could you please tell me why you want to define element in the ViewModel? It seems to be contrary to the design concept of mvvm.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT That's true. I suppose while I was originally trying to follow MVVM, at this point I'm not sticking to it(because page navigation is way more involved than it should be in MVVM for my tiny app). So now I'm just wondering if this implementation is possible. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to simply define the XAML element itself in the
> ViewModel and use that in the XAML markup of the View?

Yes, It will be work.

I tested it in WinUI3 C# and the code works fine.

Comment: Can you share the syntax of how to do that? I'm not sure how to specify the XAML object that was instantiated in the ViewModel in the markup, rather than just creating a new instance.

Comment: We don't know what *you* tested, and consequently don't know whether this is really about the problem that is being asked about. Plus, just because something XAML-related works in a C# project has no barring on a C++/WinRT project.